# asp.net web api 2 custom owin auth middleware working with Authorize attribute

Tags: authentication, asp.net-web-api, owin, claims-based-identity

I am buliding an web api, where i want to use the built-in infrastructure to handle roles and deny users access if they do not have the required role. The api is going to be run as an application on an existing site, using the site cookies for authentication.

For the purpose of authentication i've created a simple custom middleware, where cookies is validated, and if is found valid an identity with proper role is created.

The problem arises when request reaches the controller, where access is denied. As the identity i created in custom middleware is located in owin context, and not in HttpContext.Current.User.Identity, where i suppose it should be located for the Authorize attribute to work properly.

How do solve this issue with identity being in the "wrong" context?

```
using Owin;
using ThgDataApi.Security;

namespace ThgDataApi.App_Start
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.Use(typeof(ApiCookieAuthMiddleware));

        }
    }
}
```

for the sake of simplicity cookie logic has ben simplified.

```
 public class ApiCookieAuthMiddleware : OwinMiddleware
    {
        public ApiCookieAuthMiddleware(OwinMiddleware next) : base(next)
        {
        }

        public override async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
        {
            if (context.Request.Cookies.Any(x => x.Key == "c"))
            {
                var identity = new ClaimsIdentity();
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "User"));
                context.Authentication.SignIn(identity);

                await Next.Invoke(context);
            }
            else
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                context.Response.ReasonPhrase = "some error";
                return;
            }

        }
    }
```

Controller

```
[Authorize(Roles = "User")]
    public class TestController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult GetHello()
        {
            return Ok("Hello World!!!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: pass the created identity to the current thread